# Python large app: how to use other modules that might be needed or not, depending on the request given?

Tags: python

I have a web app in python and there is a main file that is a router.

The router reads the path and should:

1. only now import the module needed for the request, or
2. call the method directly. (In this case all modules needed by the app are imported at the beginning of the file)

In the first case:

```
router(path, args):
    // now import the module needed and run it
```

In the second case the app would look like:

```
from services.a import a1
from services.a import a2
from services.a import a3
from services.a import a4
from services.a import a5
from services.a import a6
// and then in the router function

rooter(path, args):
   // based on the path will call a fn
   a1(args...)
```

What is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PEP 8, "Style Guide for Python Code"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Unless you have a good reason to violate this, follow it.

Comment: So if I have 1000 modules, but I only need one per request I must import all 1000 modules and make a 1000 switch and then run that method?

Comment: I don't understand why you would use a switch for it, but the process should be persistent and so shouldn't be running all the modules for each request (not that it would anyways, since they're all in the same module).

Comment: @Totty It doesn't matter as long as you don't run it in cgi mode. But if you do and the imports are big I'd violate the rule and put the imports inside the functions.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have a big file with 10k lines with all the functions in there. Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: When I have a request I already know what service is needed to trigger, so based on that information I need to run that method in that module that is needed. To not violate "the rules" I should import at the beginning of the file all the modules I need, and then select the one I need. @rplnt: I'm running on Google App Engine (anyway I do not understand cgi mode things...) And I've made an old app with "eval" in order to load the requested service, but that is bad design too.. anyways..

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: how this answers to my problem?

Comment: GAE is persistent. Once `services.a` is imported, it's imported for good, and any further imports from it use the existing reference.

Comment: But how would you do then a Router class that based on the requested path will run the correct service?